# threshold value for ICP registration open3D python

Tags: python, registration, open3d

the function open3d.registration.registration_icp has the parameter max_correspondence_distance which is used as a threshold , I do not know its meaning, what range of values it takes or should takes. does it depend between images ? how can I set up the best value ? thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2):

At every iteration and for each point in the mesh or pcd, the registration algorithm will look for the closest point from the mesh to the target but only if there is one within max_correspondence distance. So some points in the mesh may not have a correspondence to one in the target because they are too far away. It then uses these correspondences to minimize the distance between the two.

It's important to remember that the corresponding points are evaluated at every iteration, so a point in the mesh may not have a corresponding point within max_correspondence_distance in the target on one iteration. But then after the mesh is adjusted that point may be close enough to have one in the next.